# Element is not currently visible

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm using selenium to try to log into  MyBB for a site I am a member of. I'm working on trying to make a shout box bot. (Yes I have permission to do this) The issue I am having is that the element I am trying to send data to is not displayed. It can be found but is says it is not displayed. The code says it is found but not displayed. Is there a way to make it visible?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


class shoutbox():
""" Class that will handle looging in to mybb and shout text """

    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.login_mybb()

    def login_mybb(self):
        url = r"http://www.rpgcreation.net/community/member.php?action=login"

        self.driver.get(url)

        try:
            WebDriverWait(self.driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "username")))
            print("found username")
            userName = self.driver.find_element(By.NAME, "username")
            if userName.is_displayed():
                print("username is displayed")
            else:
                print("username is not displayed")
        finally:
            self.driver.quit()


shoutbox()
```

Comment: the page has more than one element `By.NAME` `username`. You need to identify one element. You use `xpath` instead coz no unique identifier.

Comment: @nitinchawda Thanks for the suggestion. I'll give it a try once I figure out how the xpath portion works.

Comment: I finally was able to get the correct xpath going. Thanks again @nitinchawda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this xpath,

`(//input[@name='username'])[2]`

OR

`//td/input[@name='username']`